# Find coordinate on circle in 3D

Tags: geometry, circles, 3d

If I have a line in 3D space $AB$ where the gradient, $A$ and $B$ are known, how can I find the point at a given angle degrees on the circumference of the circle normal to $AB$ with centre $B$?

Edit: The angle doesn’t really matter, just want to know how to do this in principle.

Edit 2: Here is a figure of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: An angle of 60° starting from where?

Comment: A figure would be useful: see for instance https://www.geogebra.org/classic#3d

Answer (score 0):

Just find two unit vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, perpendicular between them and to line $AB$. You can then write a parametric equation for the circle as:
$$
B+r\cos\theta\ \vec u+r\sin\theta\ \vec v.
$$
Example.

If $A=(0,0,1)$ and $B=(2,2,0)$ then we can conveniently define a unit vector with direction $AB$ as
$$
\vec n={A-B\over AB}={1\over3}(-2,-2,1)
$$
and
$$
\vec u={1\over\sqrt2}(1,-1,0),
\quad
\vec v=\vec n\times\vec u={1\over3\sqrt2}(1,1,4).
$$

Comment: How do you find $\overrightarrow{u}$?

Comment: @BorisKaptsanov $$\vec u={1\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}(-n_y,n_x,0)$$